# Parsing Arguments Through Class Method

Tags: ruby

I want to send input through a calculator Class. A sample is as follows:

```
class Calculator
  def initialize(num1, num2, op)
    @num1 = num1
    @num2 = num2
    @op = op
  end

  def addition
    if @op == "+"
      sum = @num1 + @num2
    end 
    puts sum
  end
end

p calc = Calculator.new(2, 5, '+')
```

This is not working as intended. There is a way to do this with a switch statement in C++ (parsing out what function to go to based on the operand), but I am slightly confused as to how to parse input through definitions in by a class in Ruby. Any tips would be really appreciated.

Comment: Well, you confuse me too. Please explain what you would like the code to do. Obviously your `addition` method will not be called, but you have not even written a "class method" as you referenced it in the title. As it stands the `sum` variable would most likely have the wrong scope, but that is a moot point as long as `addition` won't be called. Please state the purpose of your `Calculator` class more clearly such that we may understand how it should work.

Comment: What I am hoping to accomplish with this is to execute the appropriate method depending on the operand that is entered as an argument.  For example, if the arguments are (2, 5 "+") the method addition will be executed.

Comment: make the method `addition` the line before `end`, even though its a bad idea, but it should print `sum`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `send`. Pass the string to it, together with the other operand, and that method will be executed.

```
@num1, @num2, @op = 2, 5, "+"
@num1.send(@op, @num2) # => 7

@num1, @num2, @op = 2, 5, "*"
@num1.send(@op, @num2) # => 10
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is not hard to convert your example to do something useful I will give it a shot. Try the following:

```
class Calculator
  def initialize(num1, num2, op)
    @num1 = num1
    @num2 = num2
    @op = op
  end

  def execute
    res = nil
    case @op
      when "+" 
        res = @num1 + @num2
      when "-"
        res = @num1 - @num2
    end 
    # puts res
    res
  end
end

calc = Calculator.new(2, 5, '+')
calc.execute
# => 7

calc = Calculator.new(2, 5, '-')
calc.execute
# => -3
```

This should give you an idea as the `#execute` method will return the result you expect. If you want it printed instead you can uncomment the `puts res` in there, note however, that `puts` will return a `nil`. If you do not want to call `#execute` yourself on the `Calculator` object you may include the call into the initializer as @bjhaid suggested.

As I still fail to understand what you *really* want to accomplish (just "executing the appropriate method" is usually not all you want to do, you will need the result somewhere) this might not be enough. But I hope it gives you an idea on how to continue, otherwise you would have to clarify your intensions (and drop a comment on this answer as I would not notice if you do not).